# Specify TinyMCE editor font color in WordPress?

Tags: php, css, wordpress, tinymce

I'm using TinyMCE in WordPress, and when you type in the editor, the color of the text is #333333 or rgb(51, 51, 51). What's odd is that the default color in the "Select text color" button is #eeeeee, yet when you type on page load, it's still #333333. I'm using this function in functions.php to set the colors:

```
function change_mce_options( $init ) {
    $init['theme_advanced_default_foreground_color'] = '#eeeeee';
    $init['theme_advanced_text_colors'] = 'eeeeee,ff4343,8383cc';
return $init; }
add_filter('tiny_mce_before_init', 'change_mce_options');
```

How do I change both the default font color and font family of text entered into the editor?

Comment: You may try with advanced Tinymce plugin, no need of code to do it

Comment: I'd prefer a few lines of code over throwing a new plugin into the mix.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create `my-editor-style.css` stylesheet in your theme root folder and put your styles there:

```
body#tinymce.wp-editor { 
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; 
}

body#tinymce.wp-editor a {
    color: #4CA6CF;
}
```

And finally load this file by adding following hook into your `functions.php` file:

```
add_action( 'init', 'wpse8170_add_editor_styles' );
function wpse8170_add_editor_styles() {
    add_editor_style( 'my-editor-style.css' );
}
```

Read more about [editor styles](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_editor_style) in codex.